# Display unique combination of values per ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query that returns the following structure:

```
ORDER ID | PRODUCT_NAME | DELIVERY_TYPE | PRIORITY_TYPE
```

One order may have many products. I need to get a unique combination of `Product Name, Delivery Type and Priority Type` each and every order currently have. So, if 10 orders have exactly the same `Product Name, Delivery Type and Priority Type`, I need to get it only once. 
Just removing order id from the query and getting distinct values will not help as I'll not know which records belong to the same `order id`. I believe that it can be written as a script by looping through a cursor, just wondering if there's more elegant solution using a single SQL statement.

The purpose of this exercise is the following - we're rewriting our system and new design will not allow multiple delivery types per order, so we're collapsing multiple delivery types into one. For this purpose we need to know all possible combinations of product/delivery/priority per order that exist today, so we can determine a correct single value for each unique combination.

Here is the data sample:

[Input data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mP8N.jpg)

As result of the query, I need to get only the unique sets of PRODUCT_NAME, DELIVERY_TYPE & PRIORITY_TYPE, so in the example above, I'd like to get the following:

[Output data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTIeJ.jpg)

Please note order Id's 2 & 4 do not appear here as they have the same set of values as order ID's  1 & 3 correspondingly. Actually, Order ID's are not important to have in output, they just serve as an indicator for distinct records' sets belonging to the same order.

Comment: *So, if 10 orders have exactly the same Product Name, Delivery Type and Priority Type, I need to get it only once.* Well, this is exacty the definition of `DISTINCT`. Maybe you want to switch to `GROUP BY Product Name, Delivery Type, ` and add `MAX/MIN(ORDER ID)`.

Comment: You don't need a cursor for that. However, you do need to post some sample data for anyone to be able to help you. As you have it, looks like you just need to group using `GROUP BY`.

Comment: "if 10 orders have exactly the same Product Name, Delivery Type and Priority Type, I need to get it only once. "  . . . What about the other 9 orders?

Comment: To dnoeth - your solution will return min/max order ID that have particular fields' values. I need something else -a unique list of multiple records that belong to the same Order ID.

Comment: To Gordon Linoff - I don't need list of order ID's, I just need a unique set of multiple records that belong to the same Order ID.

Comment: To Rigerta Demiri  - sorry, I can't post actual data, so I've explained the nature of each field.

Comment: Can you please post sample data and what will be the answer looking for. This will helpful to find  a solution.

Comment: @LeoDan: You don't need to post actual data, but without example nobody will be able to help you, *a unique set of multiple records that belong to the same Order ID* decribes a `DISTINCT` over all four columns.

Comment: Thank you all for responding, I've posted sample data and explained what's required in the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody suggested a pure SQL Solution, without using cursor, I'm posting here my answer with using cursor. #TEMP1 table is the table that contains input data posted in the image above.

```
DECLARE @tmp_o_id bigint
set @tmp_o_id=0
declare @tmp_str varchar(2000)
set @tmp_str=''
DECLARE @o_id bigint
declare @product_name  varchar(51)
declare @dlv_type varchar(201)
declare @pr_type varchar(201)

DECLARE @tmp_tbl TABLE (tmp_str varchar(2000))
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (o_id bigint, product_name  varchar(51), dlv_type varchar(201), pr_type varchar(201))
DECLARE @tbl2 TABLE (o_id bigint, product_name  varchar(51), dlv_type varchar(201), pr_type varchar(201))

DECLARE cursor_o CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY
FOR 
    SELECT *
    from #TEMP1 
    order by 1


OPEN cursor_o

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_o
INTO @o_id,@product_name, @dlv_type,@pr_type

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    if @tmp_o_id<>@o_id 
        begin
            if @tmp_o_id<>0
            begin           
                if not exists (select * from @tmp_tbl where tmp_str=@tmp_str) 
                    begin               
                        insert into @tbl select * from @tbl2                    
                    end                         
                delete from @tbl2
                insert into @tmp_tbl VALUES(@tmp_str)                                                       
                set @tmp_str=''
            end                 
        end
    set @tmp_str=@tmp_str+''+@product_name+''+@dlv_type+''+@pr_type
    set @tmp_o_id=@o_id
    insert into @tbl2 VALUES(@o_id, @product_name, @dlv_type,@pr_type)  
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_o
    INTO @o_id, @product_name, @dlv_type,@pr_type
END 
if not exists (select * from @tmp_tbl where tmp_str=@tmp_str) 
    begin   
        insert into @tbl select * from @tbl2                    
        delete from @tbl2
    end                         
CLOSE cursor_o;
DEALLOCATE cursor_o;

SELECT * from @tbl
```